# How to gracefully stop a Quickbooks connector incoming request with PHP?

Tags: php, quickbooks, qbxml

I have a system that uses [keith-palmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26133/keith-palmer)s PHP Integration framework.

Periodically I need to perform maintenance on the system that uses it. The QB Server with the web connector dials in automatically every 30 minutes and the server system automatically queues new orders for import - how might I send a graceful "Nothing to do" response to the quickbooks web connector to halt the request without causing any errors?

Something like a 503 - Try Later header is what I was thinking but knowing the wonders of qbXML that would probably cause all sorts of headaches!

I have looked at a response of saying "100" - which I assume means that the queue is 100 percent complete? Would sending that cause the connection to shutdown without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from the author of the framework, Keith Palmer!

---

Hi Ben,

The easiest way to do this is to set up your own authentication function, and then when you put the site in maintenance mode have that function return false so that the login from the Web Connector fails.

http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector#custom_authentication_functions

---

So easy a child could have thought of it - simply short circuit your authentication system and return a 'false' to void the connection attempt.

Tried and Tested: Works!